# Invoking Method with parameters

Tags: c#, invoke

I am writing a very simple scripting tool with my own functions.

I can invoke methods just fine with and without parameters. My main issue is parsing the parameters that the user input.
do I need to hardcore a parser myself or is there a better way to do so?

sample code

```
 public class FunctionList
    {
        public void MyMethod(string x)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(x);
        }
    }

    public void Test()
    {            
        Type type = typeof(FunctionList);
        MethodInfo method = type.GetMethod(debugBox.Text);
        FunctionList c = new FunctionList();
        method.Invoke(c, new object[] { "lorem ipsum" });
    }
```

Example user input in TextBox:

```
MyMethod(Hello World)
Sleep(500)
MyMethod(Waited 500 ms)
Sum(5, 4)
```

I will also want to add in conditions and loops, but i think that would require something other then invoking methods.

Example of what i came up with as a parser:

```
        public void Test()
    {            
        Type type = typeof(FunctionList);
        MethodInfo method = type.GetMethod(helper.GetUntilOrEmpty(debugBox.Text, "(")); //gets all text until first ( which translates to the function name
        FunctionList c = new FunctionList();
        //Handles one argument, gets the text between ( )
        int pFrom = debugBox.Text.IndexOf("(") + "(".Length;
        int pTo = debugBox.Text.LastIndexOf(")");
        string result = debugBox.Text.Substring(pFrom, pTo - pFrom);               
        //pass params        
        method.Invoke(c, new object[] { result });
    }
```

Comment: it is called [Roslyn](https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn/wiki/Scripting-API-Samples)

Comment: When parsing is what you need, you need a parser. If I didn't want to use Roslyn, I'd use NCalc. You can easily make it call .NET methods that you provide. But googling ".net expression evaluator" will turn up a wealth of options, most of them worth at least what you'll pay.

Comment: @your edit: do you have a specification for your scripting language? are strings with double quotes as delimiters and possible escape sequences for the delimiters the only type of parameter you ever need to parse? or could you just use C#, then there are so many options of dynamic code execution, that can call into the host assembly. I did it once with ANTLR, but nowadays there is no need, with several open source script engines at our disposal.

Comment: @dlatikay I will only be handling strings and int, and function take up to 3 parameters

Comment: you can do this with a simple parser. but not without one. if you're just doing this as a proof-of-concept or for learning or for fun, consider that you can have parentheses and commas inside a string literal, defying a simple `String.Split` for the argument list. Probably you cannot do without a syntax for escaping quotes inside the string, too. this can get complicated quickly.

Comment: @dlatikay Yeah, i can see how it can get complicated, could you review my edit and add anything i could add to improve it?

Comment: At the minimum, you're going to want some validation before you process it.  This looks like it would fail if there's more than one paren. You probably want a finite state machine.

Comment: @BurnsBA ofcourse, i'll make it compatible with any amount of params, this is just for the sake of example

Answer (score 0):

I have a lot of experience in dealing with such scenarios. I developed my own scripting engine (back in Adobe Flash golden age).

If you have a complex mechanism to create functions and objects than I will recommend you to write a parser that translates your custom scripting code into C#'s compile time error free code.

I have tested your code and it works fine if you already know which parameter you are gonna pass.

```
   public void Test()
    {
        Type type = typeof(FunctionList);
        MethodInfo method = type.GetMethod("MyMethod");
        FunctionList c = new FunctionList();
        // if you dont know the type of parameter passed then you have to write a parser to determine the type of the parameter right before executing the method. 

        method.Invoke(c, new object[] { "lorem ipsum" , 10});
    }

}

public class FunctionList
{
    public void MyMethod(string x, int y)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(x + " : " + y);
    }
}
```

Comment: So you say that my only option is to write my own custom parser?
i will edit with an example of what i came up with

Comment: Before I say yes... Can you provide me a little bit more info? Like sample code from your custom language and then what exactly you are trying in C# to run the generated code? I am 100% sure I have done like this before. If you tell me your exact code/needs i can just share my experience. ;)

Comment: Very simple, i create my own functions which i then invoke, each function has up to 3 parameters, and a user calls a function by typing it in a text box (multi lined), i will edit my main post so you get a better understanding, i may also want to add the possibility of setting variables and using them later on, but i suspect that the simple invoke method+parsing won't cut it. look out for my edit :)

Comment: @Dimakossover, just saw your code. and it wont work. i will get you a complete answer soon. I had the same scenario and i spent a lot of days in finding how to do that. I wrote my own langauge, its parser to generate compile time error free C# code and then compiled that code into C# and invoke it. Though your scenario is different coz you just want them to pass which funciton to invoke with params. I will get you something when i get time.